# Amazon Fire HD 10 (7th Generation), two profiles and non-working installation of Google Play Services on 2nd profile

Tags: google-play-store, tablet, google-play-services

I have an Amazon Fire HD 10 (7th Generation) with the latest version of Fire OS (5.6.0.0) installed. I would like to use two adult profiles, both should have access to the Google Play Store.

I had no problems installing the required Google APKs and apps from the Play Store in the primary profile, i.e.:

1. [Google Account Manager](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-account-manager/google-account-manager-5-1-1743759-release/google-account-manager-5-1-1743759-android-apk-download/)
2. [Google Services Framework](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-services-framework/google-services-framework-5-1-1743759-release/google-services-framework-5-1-1743759-android-apk-download/)
3. [Google Play Services](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-11-5-09-release/google-play-services-11-5-09-240-164803921-android-apk-download/)
4. [Google Play Store](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-8-4-40-release/google-play-store-8-4-40-v-all-0-pr-176415973-android-apk-download/)
5. And then apps within the Google Play Store app.

But now, when I try to do the same procesure and install the Google Play Services APK above below the secondary profile, I get the following error when trying to install:

> App not installed.

Nothing more; no error text, no error code. I've already tried rebooting the device and uninstalling the Google Apps and installing them in a different order. The crazy thing is: It already worked with two profiles before I factory resetted the device. The reason why I factory resetted was that I incorrectly added two Google accounts to the first Fire HD profile. That messed up Gmail and other apps. This is driving me insane.

Does anyone else encountered that problem and know how-to fix it / workaround it? I will not factory reset my device again, installing all apps and entering all the credentials takes hours. I am also afraid to uninstall the "Google Play Services" below the first profile, since I do not know if a new installation would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the cause of the problem and post the solution here, so it may be helpful to others.

---

**tl;dr:** Avoid version mismatch (due to automatic updates) between *Google Play Services* and *Google Play Store* apps in Fire HD profiles.

The two apps *Google Play Services* and *Google Play Store* seem to get automatically updated, no matter whether automatic updates are enabled inside of the *Google Play Store* app.

The original versions (as listed in the questions) manually installed from APKs were:

- Google Play Services: 11.5.09 (240-164803921)
- Google Play Store: 8.4.40.V-all [0] [PR] 176415973

Some time after installation I checked the version information for both apps by doing the following:

1. Open the *Settings* app.
2. Select the *Apps and Games* button below the *Device* group.
3. Select the *Manage All Apps* button.
4. Select the *All* tab.
5. Scroll until *Google Play Services* and *Google Play Store* are visible in the list.
6. Select the list entry for each app.
7. Check and compare the version information (at the top).

By doing that I've noticed that the version of both apps has changed to the following:

- [Google Play Services: 11.9.51 (234-177350961)](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-11-9-51-release/google-play-services-11-9-51-234-177350961-android-apk-download/)
- [Google Play Store: 8.5.39.W-all [0] [PR] 178322352](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-8-5-39-release/google-play-store-8-5-39-w-all-0-pr-178322352-android-apk-download)

After I've downloaded the APKs for both versions from apkmirror.com (see links above) and installed them in the second profile the installation worked flawless.

I am now able to use Google Play apps in both the primary and secondary profile.

In conclusion the cause of the problem was a version mismatch between the *Google Play Services* and *Google Play Store* apps in the primary (newer, automatically updated versions) and secondary (tries to install older versions) Fire HD profile.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Attn novice users - APKMirror.com is where you find the Play Services and Play Store versions you'll need.

Comment: I found it difficult to find an exact match for the Google Play Services and Google Play Store apps installed on the first profile, so I just used a tool to get the APKs for what was already installed (I used [File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alphainventor.filemanager&hl=en_US), but there are many apps that can be used to do this). To share the files in between the two profiles I connected the Kindle to my computer via USB, copied the files to the computer while in the first profile, then switched to the second and transferred them back.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot, that helped (Fire HD8).

Had the problem that I tried to install Google Play on the second user, but it always said "Download Pending".

Solution thanks to your steps:

1. Install for first user on tablet
2. After Google Play Services and Google Play Store are updated on first user, write down version numbers
3. Install on second user:
   3.a Google Account Manager
   3.b Google Services Framework
4. Find same versions of Google Play Services and Google Play Store from first user on APKMirror and install on second user

Comment: Glad it helped. Consider upvoting my question and answer then please.